# z-index not working on trying to place forms on top of each other

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, z-index

I am making a login page and a signup page for my program and what is supposed to happen is that they are both supposed to be stacked on top of each other but one of them is not supposed to be displayed. The problem that I am having is that they are unable to stack on top of each other. I have seen someone who said try to use `position: absoloute` but I tried that and the format of the whole website messed up so perhaps not that method. I am using boostrap classes with some of this if that helps at all.

```
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
<h1 class="burning_text">WELCOME!</h1>
<div id="main-menu" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col"></div>

        <div class="col" id="outer_container">

            <div id="main_container">

                <form id="login_form" class="form-horizontal bg-secondary animate__animated" action="javascript:void(0);">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row form-group" style="position:relative; left:10%;">
                            <label class="temporary control-label">Name:</label>
                            <input id="login_name_input" class="form-control" type = "text" required maxlength="40" placeholder="username">
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group" style="position: relative; left: 10%">
                                <label class="temporary control-label">Password:</label>
                                <input id="login_password_input" class="form-control" type = "password" required maxlength="40" placeholder="password">
                                <button id="login_alter_button" type="button" style="position: relative; bottom: 35%; left: 100%; height: 40px;"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></button>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" id="login_submit_button" style="margin: 40px; position: relative; top: 50%; right:130%;">login <i class="fas fa-door-open" style="font-size: 48px;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="switch_signup_button" type="button" style="position: relative; left: 207%; font-size: 15px; height: 30px;">switch to signup <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></button>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    
                </form>







                <form id="signup_form" class="form-horizontal bg-primary animate__animated" action="javascript:void(0);">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row form-group" style="position:relative; left:10%;">
                            <label class="temporary control-label">Name:</label>
                            <input id="signup_name_input" class="form-control" type = "text" required maxlength="40" placeholder="username">
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group" style="position: relative; left: 7%">
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <label class="temporary control-label">Password:</label>
                                <input id="signup_password_input" class="form-control" type = "password" required maxlength="40" placeholder="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <button id="signup_alter_button" type="button" style="position: relative; top: 45%; right: 90%; padding: 5px;"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" id="signup_submit_button" style="margin: 40px">signup <i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:48px;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="switch_login_button" type="button" style="position: relative; left: 93%; top: 80%; font-size: 15px; height: 30px;">switch to login <i class="fas fa-user"></i></button>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    
                </form>



            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="col"></div>

    </div>



</div>
```

Whats currently happening is that they are being stacked on top of each other in a `display: block` kind of fashion.
Here are the CSS classes I am using (the ones I made myself and the ones that are probably useful in this situation):

```
#login_form
{
    left: 100%;
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Rockwell;
    display: block;
    
}

#signup_form
{
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Rockwell;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete CSS but they stack for me. If my answer doesn't work please let me know.

### Edited

a different solution is using `display: none;` to make the second form disappear and change it back to `display:block;` again using **javaScript** when switching between forms I think that's the best solution.

Also please remember that **absolute  positioned elements are removed from the flow**

```
.main_container {
    position: relative;
}

#login_form {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Rockwell;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#signup_form {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: Rockwell;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: So what happened? for me they are overlapping because I have a demo can you show me what you got in your code?

Comment: I am not 100% too sure what you mean by "removed from the flow"

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the document flow, and thus their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions of their parents.

Comment: Check the MDN page :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position/#absolute

Comment: Well something has happened but the main problem now is to do with something else in the program that is not to exactly do with this question.